# Save results of glm into matrix in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, dataset, logistic-regression

I performed multivariable logistic regression using glm.

```
example <- glm(Death ~ age + sex + time, db, family = binomial)
```

I just want to save the results into a simple matrix in R just like this:

[image]

Where columns A= odds ratio; B= lower 95%CI; C= upper 95%CI. Each row corresponds to the results of one variable (so if age is the first variable, OR: 1.4, 95% CI: 0.9 - 1.6)

How can I do it? The problem is that the results of glm are automatically saved into a list so I don't know how to code it.

Also, is there a way maybe to put automatically in a separate column the variable to which the OR and 95%CI is referred to? I just need this table to do plots and I don't want to confound myself.

[image]

Comment: You might find the function `tidy()` from the package **broom** helpful?

Comment: @joran Thank you but I don't know how to continue because in R the results of the logistic regression are displayed with coefficients, while I need confidence intervals in the table. I manage to paste the OR with (exp(temp$estimate)) but I don't know what to do with the 95% CI.

Comment: @joran I solved it! Thank you!! I used broom so it was very useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! Hope it might be useful for someone

```
example <- glm(Death ~ age + sex + time, db, family = binomial)
CI <- exp(confint.default(example))
aOR <- exp(coefficients(example))

df<-as.data.frame(CI) %>%
                  mutate(aOR=aOR) %>%
                  filter(!row_number() %in% c(1)) 

df <- df[, c(3,1,2)]
rm(CI, example, aOR)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
summary(glm(...))$coefficients # contains estimates, standard errors and inferential statistics for all predictors
```

Estimate +/- 1.96 se result in the upper and lower 95%-Confidence interval. So the code below should do the trick:

```
# for 95%-Conficene Intervals around regression coefficients (coefficients = log(odds))
df<- as.data.frame(summary(example)$coefficients)
df$CI_lower <- df$Estimate-1.96*df$`Std. Error`
df$CI_upper <- df$Estimate+1.96*df$`Std. Error`
matrix<-as.matrix(df[c("Estimate","CI_lower","CI_upper")])
```

Comment: Thank you! However when I tried this I got different results from the actual OR/CI, maybe because the function exp is needed.

Comment: Seems like I didn't read your post carefully enough, you wanted confidence intervals around the odd-ratios, my approach returns confidence intervals around the regression coefficients. Regression coefficients can be transformed into odd-ratios and vice versa, the transformation should be this: _exp(coefficient)=odds_, respectively _log(odds)=coefficient_ (see this link: https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faq-how-do-i-interpret-odds-ratios-in-logistic-regression/).

Comment: I posted the solution below! I did like you said in the last comment :)

Comment: Of course I am not expert so if you want to make changes to the code so it's better please do so!